# "dependency.platforms.android.componentDescriptors" is not allowed

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

I have a project that was working but, when I erased and clone from github again, the project doesn't worked anymore. The warn that trigger in the build and when I start the App is:

WARN Package react-native-screens has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: "dependency.platforms.android.componentDescriptors" is not allowed

I know that has nothing to do with the versions of the react-native-screens because other devs are using the same project and it is working.  Can it be some permission or anything like that? (Android Studio for emulation)